# How to copy or duplicate a ViewController in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to copy & paste/duplicate the View Controller Scene in Xcode using the Interface Builder and not code?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In `Interface Builder`, instead of trying to copy/paste directly from the visual representation of your `ViewController`, do it from the list on the left.

The new View Controller will be pasted right on top of the original one.

[image]

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but how do I add View Controller Scene to my Project Navigator? It's not there

Comment: You have to right click in your project navigator and create a new file. Select "Cocoa Touch Class" and create a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Then don't forget to set the custom class name for your scene in Interface Builder

Comment: One last question, I apologize. After I follow those steps I have a .swift code file, how do I convert this into the View Controller Scene? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just for clarity - The view controller gets copied exactly on top of the existing view controller. You need to drag it from on top of it. It can appear confusing.

Comment: Years later, this answer is still getting upvotes. I added your clarification to the answer @VarunNath