# View Controller Gets Smaller When I Copy/Paste It (Xcode 7, Swift 2)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7

I would like to point out that I am aware of this question: [How to copy or duplicate a ViewController in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552751/copy-duplicate-viewcontroller)
and that I followed its instructions.

When I do copy/paste said ViewController, the new "pasted" one is smaller than the original.
[The two ViewControllers: One bigger and the other smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA9eE.png)

Another discrepancy between the two is that I can't seem to select the "pasted" ViewController's Navigation Bar to change its title.

What shows up in the Utilities area when I select the Pasted's nav bar instead of the "Title", "Prompt" and "Back Button" I get when I select the original's nav bar: [Pasted's nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG1Ab.png).

Is there any way to get it to be the same size as it's counterpart and/or let me select it's Navigation Bar so that I can change its title?

Sorry if the question is a bit strange but bear with me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two separate issues:

1. When you copy/pasted that VC, it no longer inherited from a segue its estimated size, so if you had for whatever reason a different size specified for the view it segued from, that is the size for the old VC, but the new one just gets the default size. If this is indeed the case, you can always change the size of the new VC by under Size Inspector, choosing Freeform and specifying it.
2. To get the navigation bar back, drag a `Navigation Item` from the Storyboard Object library onto your new VC and you can re-title it (and delete that button you added).

Comment: Thanks! I want you to know that your answer really helped me ;)

Comment: You're welcome - both of those issues are some of the *interesting* parts of SB.